# ASP.net MVC cross application POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, antiforgerytoken

I have several ASP.net MVC applications deployed on a single site in IIS. All of the applications are using forms authentication, and all of the applications are configured to use the same machine key.

One of the applications is a 'base site' which provides navigation to the other applications and is where login/logout functionality is being handled. As it stands, a user can log in on the base site and visit the other applications and they will still be authenticated, which is working as intended.

I have a logout form in the header of my shared layout views which submits a post request to the logout action in a controller belonging to the base site. When I submit this form from the base site, the logout works as expected. But if I try to submit the form from any of the other sites, I receive the error message:

```
"The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match."
```

This is what my log off action looks like in my Security controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        return Redirect("~/");
    }
```

This is what my form looks like in the base site view:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Security", FormMethod.Post, null))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input type="submit"  value="Log Off"/>
                }
```

Because of the way the directories are set up the other sites use a slightly different version of the same form to call the logout action from the base site:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "../Security", FormMethod.Post, null))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input type="submit"  value="Log Off"/>
                }
```

The base site is at the root of the directory, and the other applications are contained in their own folder within that root.

None of the views I have tried this on have any conflicting forms or antiforgery tokens, and the machine key among all the apps seems to be configured properly or else I don't think the authentication would be working at all. I am considering just redirecting to the base site and performing the logout action from there, but if there is another more simple solution that I have yet to come across that would be nice.

Comment: Does your web applications rest in one solution or you have different solution for each application?

Comment: Originally they are in different solutions, although they have been published.

Comment: Have you tried to log off with different timings? i mean log off from where you want the moment you just signed and let me know what happens

Comment: As far as I can tell the behavior is persistent regardless of the timing.

Answer (score 0):

The `AntiForgeryToken` works by creating a hidden field and a Cookie with the same token (see [this blod post](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/what-is-antiforgerytoken-and-why-do-i.html)). Since your form is being posted to another url, I think that the cookie is either not being transmitted along with the POST or your browser still has a cookie from a former request to your base site and therefore transmits a wrong one. Does this behaviour also occur after deleting the cookies (to ensure that no old ones are being used)?

Comment: Clearing the cookies and attempting to logout without loading a new page after gives the error "The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.". If I attempt to navigate to a different page after deleting the cookies I am sent to the login page, so by deleting the cookies I am essentially being logged out.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to solve this issue is move the LogOff action into a custom controller class which all of my controllers were already inheriting from.

```
    public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {           
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            //Redirect to home page when logging off.
            return Redirect("~/");
        } 
    }
```

And then simply changed my logout form to call the LogOff action from the current controller, rather than specifiying the Security controller in the base site:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "", FormMethod.Post, null))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input type="submit"  value="Log Off"/>
                }
```

I am not sure if there is a way to get my original version to work or not, so for now I think I am going to go with this.